# Is it good practice to inject variables in a Utility class?

Tags: java, spring

I have the below Utility class in Java.

```
    public class Utils {
       private static Properties commonProps;

       private Utils() {}

       private static setCommonProps(Properties commonProps) {
           Utils.commonProps = commonProps;
       }

       public static boolean staticMethod1() {
           commonProps.get("xyz");
       }

       public static void staticMethod2() {
       }
    }
```

And we initialize "commonProps" with the help of Spring function org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean.

Is there anything wrong in this design of code? Can this have any bad effects?
Is it a good practice to have such variable initialization for Utility classes?

NOTE: Here "Properties commonProps" is just a placeholder. Any common member that need to be used in this class which has to be injected during startup.

Answer (score 2):

In general, dependency injection is a good thing as it leads to better designs that are easier to test. In your particular case, you have to look at what you are trying to achieve.

It appears that you are trying to provide a single point to access properties through and add some value over the standard Java `Properties` API. For example, by providing a `getBoolean()` equivalent.

With regards to the single point of access you'll need to consider threading issues. However, as long as you can guarantee that your utility class is configured before you use its static methods you should be okay.

With regards to extending the `Properties` API, you might be better served using one of the existing libraries rather than incurring the cost of writing and maintaining your own. For example, I've found [Apache Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/) to be quite good.

Comment: Here commonProps is just a placeholder. Any member that need to used by multiple functions in this class which need to be injected during startup.

Answer (score 1):

Do not not have any mutability in static fields. That is an anti-pattern. Also do not inject static fields using Spring. Doing these things will make your code unwieldily to work with, and very hard to test.

You already have the ability to use `@Value` to inject fields with properties within beans. Although this is not dynamic but you really shouldn't have dynamic properties (although it's possible IMO it's not a good idea). Think of properties as startup constants or something. They shouldn't change.